# Android Matrix how to postRotate with a point specified?

Tags: java, android

default rotate center is View center , but now I want matrix rotate from Bottom?

Android API has a method:  but I don't kown what are the paramters meaning.

Open Declaration `boolean android.graphics.Matrix.postRotate(float degrees, float px, float py)`

Postconcats the matrix with the specified rotation. M' = R(degrees, px, py) * M

Parameters:
degrees 
px 
py

Answer (score 3):

the values of `px` and `py` are  the `pivot` point of the object around which you want to rotate.